# Deciding between two methods to check if a row exists (more subqueries VS more left joins)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to fetch one product information using joins from different tables. I have three additional tables (review,thread,award) and I'd like to check whether records exist relating to this specific product. If they exist, return a non-null value, otherwise null. There is a possibility that more of this type of checking will be added to the query in the future.

Which query would you prefer performance wise to test if records exists?

Using `exists` with multiple subqueries:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id,p.name,m.model,m.model_id,b.brand,me.merchant,
         EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM review WHERE product_id = :id) AS has_review,
         EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM thread WHERE product_id = :id) AS has_thread,
         EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM award WHERE product_id = :id) AS has_award
        FROM product p 
        INNER JOIN model m ON m.model_id = p.model_id
        INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = m.brand_id
        INNER JOIN merchant me ON me.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
        WHERE p.product_id = :id
        LIMIT 1";

$dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Using multiple left joins:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id,p.name,m.model,m.model_id,b.brand,me.merchant,
        (t.product_id is not null) AS has_thread,
        (r.product_id is not null) AS has_review,
        (a.product_id is not null) AS has_award
        FROM product p 
        INNER JOIN model m ON m.model_id = p.model_id
        INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = m.brand_id
        INNER JOIN merchant me ON me.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
        LEFT JOIN review r ON re.product_id = p.product_id
        LEFT JOIN thread t ON t.product_id = p.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN award a ON a.product_id = a.product_id
        WHERE p.product_id = :id
        LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless... and "comma FROM" ain't gonna work

Comment: @Strawberry Updated. Thanks

Comment: @sagi, neither your answer, nor your rationale is correct.  Both will reach into `review`, etc, for _each_ row of `product`.  (Granted, `LIMIT 1` will stop either one, but I don't think that was your point.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is much preferable.

For performance, for either version, you want indexes on `review(product_id)`, `thread(product_id)`, and `award(product_id)`.

Why is using `EXISTS` better?  When no matching rows exist in the three tables, then the two versions should be equivalent (minus the typo in the last `on` clause on the second query).  However, when rows do exist, then the second version will create cartesian products of those rows, throwing off both the results and performance.

Note:  I would be inclined to write the `EXISTS` clause using correlated subqueries, so the parameter is only referenced once:

```
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM review r WHERE r.product_id = p.product_id) AS has_review,
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM thread t WHERE t.product_id = p.product_id) AS has_thread,
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM award a WHERE a.product_id = p.product_id) AS has_award,
```